# My text isn't aligning on the right in my table. Why?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align text and images in a table for my navbar. There are two columns.
The problem is that the text and the image on the left column (class "**NavAccueil**") are aligned on the left (at least it looks like it) but the texts on the right column ("**NavWarp**") are not aligned on the right of my table. I don't know why. Here's the code (It might be very bad, I'm new at this)

```css
#BarreNavigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/CounterStrike3.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a58e188e;
  border-width: 0.5vh;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  font-family: "Mono";
}

#BarreNavigation a {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: text-shadow 250ms ease;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 2vh;
  padding-right: 2vh;
}

#BarreNavigation a:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #ff7300;
}

.NavAccueil {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px black);
  transition: filter 250ms ease;
}

.NavAccueil :hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px #ff7300)
}

.NavAccueilIcon {
  width: 4vh;
  vertical-align: -10%;
  padding-right: 1vh;
}

.NavWarp {
  width: 60%;
}

.NavWarpText {
  background-color: rgba(49, 39, 10, 0.411);
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="BarreNavigation">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="NavAccueil">
        <a href="Index.htm"><img src="Assets/Images/IconSite/Accueil.png" class="NavAccueilIcon">Accueil</a>
      </td>
      <td class="NavWarp">
        <a href="#Presentation" class="NavWarpText">Presentation</a>
        <a href="#ModesJeu" class="NavWarpText">Modes De Jeu</a>
        <a href="#Cartes" class="NavWarpText">Les Cartes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

*Also, I've a problem where the text in the "boxes" on the right are like cut when the width they have is not enough so they get cut and one part of the text in the box stays on the top and the other one goes on the bottom of the navbar so the boxes are like cut.*

Anyways, that's another problem.
So if anybody knows how to align that text on right, I would be happy to learn from you.

Comment: I've tried aligning NavWarp on the right with align-items, align-text, align-content but nothing seemed to work...

Comment: Add `table { border: 1px solid red; }` and you see that the stuff is aligned to the right and you actually have a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` by default is only as wide as its content.

Add

```
table { table-layout: fixed; min-width: 100%; }
```

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; min-width: 100%; }

#BarreNavigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("../Assets/Images/CounterStrike3.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: fit-content;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a58e188e;
  border-width: 0.5vh;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  font-family: "Mono";
}

#BarreNavigation a {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: text-shadow 250ms ease;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 2vh;
  padding-right: 2vh;
}

#BarreNavigation a:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #ff7300;
}

.NavAccueil {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px black);
  transition: filter 250ms ease;
}

.NavAccueil :hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px #ff7300)
}

.NavAccueilIcon {
  width: 4vh;
  vertical-align: -10%;
  padding-right: 1vh;
}

.NavWarp {
  width: 60%;
}

.NavWarpText {
  background-color: rgba(49, 39, 10, 0.411);
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="BarreNavigation">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="NavAccueil">
        <a href="Index.htm"><img src="Assets/Images/IconSite/Accueil.png" class="NavAccueilIcon">Accueil</a>
      </td>
      <td class="NavWarp">
        <a href="#Presentation" class="NavWarpText">Presentation</a>
        <a href="#ModesJeu" class="NavWarpText">Modes De Jeu</a>
        <a href="#Cartes" class="NavWarpText">Les Cartes</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It's starting to look better but there's some sort of padding on the right. Is that normal?

Edit: Nevermind, I added "text-align: right" and now it's normal. Thanks for you help, it saved me a lot of time of research!

Comment: You are doing this yourself: `#BarreNavigation a { padding-right: 2vh; }`